# The type org.springframework.data.repository.Repository cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am new for spring Boot, I got this problem when I follow the Spring Guide-Accessing data with MySQL

I got an Error in my STS IDE, I don't know what's the hell happening.
In the `src/main/java/UserRepository.java`

```
 package hello;

 import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

 import hello.User;



  public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

STS does warn me about this mistake, I ignore it until I run `Cmd: mvn spring-boot`
so I am back to check the warning, it is:

```
The type org.springframework.data.repository.Repository cannot be 
resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Thanks very much for helping me!

I bulid the project using Maven as recommended,the Pom.xml is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-mysql-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply some spring boot standards to the code

1. Keep your boot application on top of the package, in your case your BootApplication should be in hello package. Like shown in below

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class BootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
   SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
   }
   }
   ```
2. Now keep your repository inside the sub-package of hello. In your case it should be in hello.repository

Now try to run with BootApplication.

Comment: Let me know the results also

Comment: Or simply,I can explain my problem in another way.Download the accessing data using sql from sts,run the complete version,it doesn't work ,Alas

Comment: @oneslide I am able to run the project successfully
Do below
1. Update your maven project so that all dependencies will be included in it.
2. Now select BootApplication and simply run it as java application.

Comment: It doesn't relevant about how I run it !I guess,in my development environment,either CrudRepository and JpaRepository can't be resolved   even their package spring *data-* is imported,I do exactly what you told me,nothing change.Oh,in my log, there are[error] can't read  读取C:\Users\onesl\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar,bad signature,,does my maven repository lack some critical packages,my maven version-Apache Maven 3.5.3 
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Comment: I had hit by such error earlier...It is because of the corrupted jar. Go to the location of aspectj and delete aspectjweaver folder. Now try to make clean build again... Do this for all such errors.

Comment: Yep,Buddy,You're right,maybe it is my unzip tools' mistake which parse the maven zip in a wrong way!anyway,I make it,thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Buddy,It doesn't work anyway.This Exception is caused by CrudRepository.The eclipse can't resolve this class.My project is very simple,I get this project from spring website.its guide--Accessing data with MySQL

And now my project is completely same as [gs-accessing-data-mysql-complete]

The Spring official Website think it is successful project,and let the trainer to check [gs-accessing-data-mysql-initial] against [gs-accessing-data-mysql-complete]
.Howerver,even the later can't be build successfully.My project structure:

```
 src
     +main
        +java
          +hello
              --Application.java
              --MainController.java
              --User.java
              --UserRepository.java
```

and the log info ,I had better show you about the digest:
1.[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project gs-mysql-data: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController' defined in file [D:\workbunch\Spring Workbunch\gs-accessing-data-mysql-initial\target\classes\hello\MainController.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [hello.MainController] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@6424f2f4]: org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository: org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository -> [Help 1]